# Python script from systemctl at launch

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2

I have 3 systemd services I created that run a Python script and pass a key argument because the scripts download datasets that require that key. When I enable the service it works just fine,  but if I reboot the EC2 instance its on it fails on launch with:

```
(code=exited, status=255)
```

I want it to run on launch because I have a workflow that uses EventBridge to trigger a Lambda function that turns on the instance at specific time to download the dataset to S3 and begin the ETL process.  Why would the service run as intended with `$sudo systemctl start service-name.service` but fails on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, this will depend on how you're running the EC2. Basically, there are two ways.

**Via Cloud-init / EC2 userdata**

You can specify if the script will be executed on the first boot (when the EC2 is created), every (re)boot, etc.

You can check the officials' docs for that:

[Cloud-init: Event and Updates](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/events.html)

[AWS - Run commands on your Linux instance at launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

[How can I utilize user data to automatically run a script with every restart of my Amazon EC2 Linux instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/)

**Via Linux systemd**

You can use the example below (just remove the comments and/or just/add the `Requires` and `After` if it's needed.)

```
## doc here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html#[UNIT]_SECTION_OPTIONS
[Unit]
Description=Startup script
# Requires=my-other-service.target
# After=After=network.target my-other-service.target

## doc here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html#OPTIONS
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/myscripts/startup.sh

## doc here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html#[INSTALL]_SECTION_OPTIONS
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```